# Custom fields in User registration, how to save?

Tags: 7, forms

I thought that I needed to, in my submit handler function, call user_save() to save my user profile data.  But when I call user_save I get duplicate entry errors because it appears user_save is being called twice.

here's a snippet of code:

```
function all_data_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {


  $fname = $form_state['values']['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value'];
  $lname = $form_state['values']['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value'];


$edit = array(
  'name' => $form_state['values']['name'],
  'pass' => user_password(),
  'mail' => $form_state['values']['mail'],
  'init' => $form_state['values']['init'],
  'status' => 0,
  'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
    'field_first_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' =>
$form_state['values']['field_first_name']))),

);


user_save(drupal_anonymous_user(), $edit);
<snipped>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to programmatically do that when you can manage custom fields through the UI. Or maybe you need to install the Entity API module for that. I forgot if that functionality is in core or by the Entity API.

Comment: I have a customized user registration page, that has various profile fields that the user can populate.  It's that data I can't seem to get saved to the database.  Entity API is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if you set your profile to be hidden in your module, you can't save any data to that profile.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist use code I suggest below method

```
function all_data_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$fname = $form_state['values']['field_first_name']['und'][0]['value'];
$lname = $form_state['values']['field_last_name']['und'][0]['value'];
$name=trim($form_state['values']['name']);
$myuser=user_load_by_name($name);
if(!empty($myuser)){
        $edit = array(
                'field_first_name' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' =>$form_state['values']['field_first_name']))),
                // .. and every field you want to save
                );
        user_save($myuser, $edit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough points to comment yet, but make sure the Field UI module is enabled, then in /admin/config/people/accounts/fields you can add/remove as you see fit. When adding fields, there is an option to 'Display on user registration form.'
[image: field on account]

Comment: Yep, Entity UI is installed and Display on user registration form is check.  The issue I am having is when the user is on that form and he enters all the data, none of the profile fields are being saved to the database.

Comment: @Steven That's strange. Are you sure you looked at the table field_data_{field_machine_name} and filter the entity_type to 'user'? Also, since you know about the Entity UI, why are you trying to save it programmatically?

Comment: I am customizing the User registration page, so that in addition to username and email I am collecting First Name, Last Name, etc.  These are all profile fields I've created.  When fill out the form, the normal items are saved ( username etc ) but the field_* items are not being saved.  That's what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: What is the outcome if you remove/disable the code you shared above?

Comment: If I remove that code, the user gets created but none of the profile field info is saved.  I can't quite grasp, reading forum postings and the Drupal API pages what I am missing here.  The user gets created.  None of the profile fields are added to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Save the new users with rudimentary data and then use [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity).

I am sure this entity module exposes API to load and attach the other fieldable data and save user entities.